# Create an sdk program to display a message in the centre of the window?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, sdk

The above question is asked for my practical exams of Visual Programming. Actually I dont want the codes. I just need to know how to create an SDK program in Visual Studio and where to put the codes.

Answer (score 0):

[Creating Win32 Applications (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx)

> This walkthrough shows how to create a basic Win32-based application that displays "Hello, World!" in a window.